# How to resolve a Local Converter issue with documents4j

Tags: java

`document4j` looks like a great api and I'd love to use it. I just want to bulk convert docx to pdf on my mac (with Microsoft office installed).

I have written this but I get the error that the LocalConverter cannot be resolved. What am I doing wrong? Have I imported the correct jars?

```
package Input;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;


import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import com.documents4j.api.DocumentType;
import com.documents4j.api.IConverter;

public class TBB {



    public static FileInputStream convert(InputStream docxInputStream) throws FileNotFoundException {   

        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("/Users/sebastianzeki/mydoc.docx"))) {
            IConverter converter = LocalConverter.builder().build();
            converter
                    .convert(docxInputStream).as(DocumentType.DOCX)
                    .to(outputStream).as(DocumentType.PDF)
                    .prioritizeWith(1000).schedule();
            inputStream = new FileInputStream("/Users/sebastianzeki/mydoc.docx");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return inputStream;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

documents4j is not compatible with Mac. Look at your stacktrace and you will find something like: `com.documents4j.throwables.ConverterAccessException: Unable to run script: /Applications/Tomcat-9.0.1/temp/1564683313105-0/word_start775650809.vbs` Documents4j is running a generated vbScript under the hood. There is no way for mac to run vbScript as far as I know. I had to install a Windows vm with Word installed on my server and use the documents4j remote api to call into the windows vm to do the conversions.